# How to get the online crypto hash of a serialized .NET object?

Tags: .net, hash, stream

I am trying to compute the cryptographic hash (say SHA2) of the serialized representation of a .NET object. I am starting with the object itself, not yet serialized. The serializer is available can be called on any `Stream`.

As I have no use for the serialized representation itself, I would like to pipe the data - while serializing - into a `Stream` and have the hash computed [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm), requesting only minimal memory allocation in the process.

What is the suggested way to achieve that in C#/.NET?

Comment: Are you starting with the serialized representation or with a runtime instance of the object? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Indeed, thanks! Just modified the question to clarify.

Comment: It seems like providing your own stream that incrementally computes the hash (which is a feature exposed by API of just about all message digest algos) would accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is more or less where I am heading. I can see that there are classes like HashStream http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.IdentityModel/System/IdentityModel/HashStream.cs,8b6779f566e27e91 lying around. I am wondering if there is not already a "canonical" way of doing this.

Comment: There probably isn't mainly because a crypto hash of a serialized object is mildly contradictory.